# generate dropdown using angularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to dynamically add a **dropdown** using `$sce.trustAsHtml()` function but I am getting an empty list in the UI. Here is the code:

```
$scope.addRowtrain = function() {
    $scope.locomotivesList = [{"name": "loco1", "value":"1"}, {"name": "loco2", "value":"2"}];
    tableData[id] = $sce.trustAsHtml('CTRun'+counter++);    
    tableData[type] = $sce.trustAsHtml("<select data-ng-model='selectedLoco' data-ng-options='loco.name for loco in locomotivesList'></select>");
 }
```

In the HTML, I want to render it as a table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in tableData track by $index">
        <td ng-repeat="(k, p) in data track by $index"><span ng-bind-html=p>{{p}}</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="addRowtrain()">Add Run</a>
...
</table
```

but it is displaying an empty table, please help

Comment: Shouldn't `tableData` be: `$scope.tableData`?

Comment: oh sorry i missed the line, tableData is an object, after that I am creating an array as $scope.tableData.push(tableData);

Answer (score 0):

you are adding it dynamically you must not pass binding values instead pass Complete JSON object.

It's working with 
[this example](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input)

`md-select` in angular material

Comment: how do i pass the complete json Object, can u plz give me an example?

Comment: Try to look into above example it has every thing inside it